# Cannot find plot function in GPy library (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, gpy

I am using the [GPy](https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPy) library in Python 2.7 to perform Gaussian Process regressions. I started by following the tutorial notebooks provided in the GitHub page.

Sample code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x : np.sin(x**2)

kernel = GPy.kern.RBF(input_dim=1, variance=1., lengthscale=1.)

X=np.random.rand(2,1)
Y=f(X)

m = GPy.models.GPRegression(X,Y,kernel)
m.optimize_restarts(num_restarts = 10,verbose=False)

fig=m.plot()
plt.show()
```

The weird thing I witnessed is that there is no **plot** function implemented in the **GPRegression** class (*ok, it's just a small sub-class of **GP**.*), nor in its super-class (**GP**), nor in its super-super-class (**Model**)... all located in **GPy.core**.

The plot function that is executed when I call **m.plot()** is in **GPy.plotting.gpy_plot** (which does not contain any class, but still uses the "self" keyword as function argument - but maybe it's just a "bad" name for a function argument ?).

I cannot see how a **GPy.core.GP** object can access this plot function (at first sight, there is no link whatsoever between the two python files - Ctrl+F "plot" in **GPy/core/gp.py** gives nothing for example).

When I call

```
vars(GPy.models.gp_regression.GP).keys()
```

, the plot function is indeed there, although not directly implemented in **GPy.core.GP**.

Same thing for : (Minimal reproducible example)

```
import GPy.core.gp
import GPy.likelihoods
import GPy.kern
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

GPy.core.gp.GP.__dict__.keys()
```

Any idea of *how* **GP** calls the plot function in **gpy_plot**, and *why* it is coded this way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plotting library gets "injected" in GPy/GPy/plotting/__init__.py's [`inject_plotting()`](https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPy/blob/v1.0.9/GPy/plotting/__init__.py#L36).  Here the line for `plot()`:

```
    from ..core import GP
    ...
    GP.plot = gpy_plot.gp_plots.plot
```

I assume the reason for this design was that it allows easily changing the plotting library *on-the-fly* via [`change_plotting_library()`](https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPy/blob/v1.0.9/GPy/plotting/__init__.py#L8).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to get things clear :
1. In this \__init__ file, the GP.plot function is created, meaning that all instances of the GP class _will (as soon as this line of code is executed)_ have this plot object method. Am I right ?
2. When does this code get executed ? Once I initialize a GP object, say **m**, how come the \__init__.py file of another folder gets executed ?
Thank you

Comment: The assignment to `GP.plot` modifies the [_class object_](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects), so instances can access `plot()`.  (This works even if the class object is modified _after_ the instance is created.)  The \_\_init__.py gets executed on `import`.  E.g., `import GPy.core.gp` executes GPy/\_\_init__.py and GPy/core/\_\_init__.py.  And the former has `from . import plotting`.